# NFC - Send tag or NDEF message on Tap

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

Is it possible to send a NDEF message without input from the user?

I would like to use NFC in the following scenario: The user taps Device on NFC reader. NFC reader receives message as response.

Essentially I want the device to operate as a Tag i.e. without input from the user.

I know KitKat 4.4 Supports HCE (Host card emulation) although i'd like a solution with greater device support such as NDEF messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Android device receives an **NDEF** Message (*for example by reading an NFC tag*) it processes it through a dispatch mechanism to determine an activity to launch.

Use `NdefMessage(byte[])` to construct an **NDEF Message from binary data**, or `NdefMessage(NdefRecord[])` to construct *from* one or more NdefRecords.

The type of the first record in the message has special importance for message dispatch, so design this record carefully.
**Get the NDEF Records inside this NDEF Message.**

An **NdefMessage** always has *one or more NDEF Records*: so the following code to retrieve the first record is always safe (no need to check *for null or array length >= 1):*

```
 NdefRecord firstRecord = ndefMessage.getRecords()[0];
```

Returns:
**array of one or more NDEF records.**

A one-tap approach is not possible using Beam on two Android devices

> (*note that with other devices, particularly if one is Android and one
>   is a dedicated NFC reader or a device where you can control the NFC
>   functionality on a low level or a device that emulates an NFC tag).*

However, a two-tap approach is possible between two Android devices with only little modifications to your existing scenario.

You simply need to add a foreground dispatch that intercepts your incoming NDEF message and consequently prevents Android from restarting your activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
            0);
    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pi, null, null);
}
```